# how to embed a public instagram feed in a website without using widgets?

Tags: embed, instagram-api, feed

so i've been researching for a few hours and i can't seem to find a way to do this. I've learned that Instagram have closed off all their old APIs, which are all the old answers i've found in the solutions all over Stackoverflow or in tutorials anywhere online.

The only one left on Instagram's developer website restricts me to getting **my own** feed and embedding that, while I need to access a **public** feed.

I  have tried using a widget to access a public feed, namely this one : https://instawidget.net/generate,  and that worked, but I need the data to be in JSON format, **not** to be in the form the widget represents it in.

Is there *currently* any way to do that? to access a public feed on instagram and be able to get the data in JSON format? i.e. without a widget OR the currently very limited API of Instagram's developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to support only Instagram Business Accounts you can try to look at new [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api) for Instagram. At the moment it is not working for regular Instagram accounts, only for business type of account. You can get access to JSON format if your app passes the review. Otherwise it is not really possible to get such feed by any official APIs.

Comment: yeah, i've been searching around and finally came to that conclusion too. I did however try using the old API, it still works but for **private** accounts and with ridiculous limitations, and it will be deprecated finally in 2020 :/ I had hoped to find anything else but i couldn't.. thank you anyway